# Supervisor throws spawnerr for all programs

Tags: python, linux, permissions, centos

I'm trying to configure supervisor on an EC2 Amazon Linux Ami instance. I installed supervisor with sudo easy_install supervisor and put its config file in /etc/supervisor.conf. Currently the file look like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
chmod=2775
chown=supervisor:my_app
umask=022

;[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
;port=127.0.0.1:9001        ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/var/run/supervisor/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
minfds=1024
minprocs=200
user=supervisor

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
;username=chris
;password=123
;prompt=mysupervisor
;history_file=~/.sc_history

[program:celeryd]
command=/srv/my_app/venv/bin/python /srv/my_app/manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=INFO
directory=/srv/my_app
user=celeryd
numprocs=1
autostart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs=600
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
priority=998
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-worker.log

[program:celerybeat]
command=/srv/my_app/venv/bin/celery -A my_app beat
directory=/srv/my_app
user=celerybeat
numprocs=1
autostart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs=600
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
priority=998
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-beat.log

[program:django]
command=/srv/my_app/venv/bin/python /srv/my_app/manage.py runserver
directory=/srv/my_app
user=my_app
numprocs=1
autostart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs=600
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
priority=998
stdout_logfile=/var/log/my_app/django-server.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/my_app/django-server.log

[group:my_app]
programs=celeryd,celerybeat,django
priority=999
```

I start supervisor by running:

```
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor.conf
```

The process starts up fine but I get the following errors:

```
2016-06-14 11:35:33,170 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'celeryd': EACCES
2016-06-14 11:35:33,170 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'celerybeat': EACCES
2016-06-14 11:35:33,171 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'django': EACCES
```

all my log directories are created and I'm finding very little other resources online to trouble shoot this issue.

Comment: `EACCES`might indicate access problems? Wrong paths / permissions what not.

Comment: any advice on how to start troubleshooting where the permission issues might be?

Comment: Well, I would check if `/var/log/celery/celery-worker.log`has some info, if `/srv/my_app` and subfolders work well for `celery`et al. ... to start with.

Comment: I starting django, celeryd and celerybeat with sudo and then the command listed in each program,  everything appears to be working that way.